# PHPExcel does not return the cell value with text formatting

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

In my excel cell, I have a string as shown below -

> This is just the **dummy description** to test the html
>   encoding.
>  So 
>   **Please ignore**

Which I am trying to extract using PHPExcel library using method - `getCellByColumnAndRow(6, $row)->getValue()`. But this method returns me a plane text without formatting as below -

> This is just the dummy description to test the html encoding. So
>   Please ignore

A little help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know a lot this librairy, did you try stuff like use `->getValue()->getRichTextElements();` ? i got it from here https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/227

Comment: Also i don't want to bother you but PHPExcel is kinda deprecated

Comment: I tried using getRichTextElements(), it throws **unable to handle request** exception with **HTTP ERROR 500**. 
I am using PHP 5.6, isn't it working for this version?

Comment: @DIGVJSS What if try `getFormattedValue()`?

Comment: It still gives me a plain text.